# 12V and 24V battery system with charging

Tags: batteries, parallel, charging, series

I am trying to make an electrical system for an automotive application.

We have two 12V batteries.

The car itself will run at 12V, all ECUs and components will operate here.

The starter motor, however, requires 24V.

I have sketched simplified schematic below which shows the basic configuration. This allows for 24V only where required (starter motor) and does not interupt the 12V system to the rest of the car when the 24V is engaged/disengaged.

- Vaux = main 12v battery
- Vcrank = cranking battery
- Rcrank = starter motor
- Raux = vehicle load
- IgnitionSw = Ignition switch for all electrical items
- CrankSw = engages the starter motor

[image: Circuit Diagram details 12v and 24v systems]

The question comes with charging. The alternator on the engine can only be 12V or 24V. We have no facility to include a DCDC but both batteries need charging and maintaining.

Is there a way of wiring this in the required way? Relays, interlocks, SPDTs, etc. all fine. Just want to avoid anything with software for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Wouldn't having them, by default, in parallel and then only placing them in series while starting (and disconnecting from charging then) be a way? Does that sound okay to you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let's revisit the "no DC-DC converter" statement because I don't think a switching setup that can handle starter motor currents is going to be smaller, simpler, lighter, or cheaper than using a converter.